# Automatic jQuery types in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, webdriver-io

I am using [wdio](http://webdriver.io) to create UI tests. Wdio uses `$` and `$$` globals to search for elements as such:

```
private get logo() { return $("#logo") }
private get menuItems() { return $$("nav .nav-item") }
```

VSCode is automatically recognizing `$` global as `JQueryStatic<HTMLElement>`. `$$` is working correctly as `WebdriverIO.Client<WebdriverIO.RawResult<WebdriverIO.Element>>[]`. Compiler has no problems and we have no jQuery types installed in project.

Is there a way to disable native types, or force VSCode to use only types in `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

In settings is field `typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition`, set it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was having the `@types/jquery` package installed in a sub-repo.